# How to embed dlls needed for crypto and crypto/libcrypto work in a racket standalone executable on windows

Tags: dll, racket, embed

As the title says, I'm trying to build a standalone executable that depends on the crypto library but whenever I try to run it on the machine I need, i get the exception
`encrypt: could not get implementation`

what do I need to do for it to work as intended?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out that I needed to understand how raco distribute works, raco exe only creates an executable that looks for dependencies in your machine, but with raco distribute you can create a folder with the executable within and with a folder structure containing all the dependencies that the executable will try to reach if said folder structure is present.